# Quicksort: compute the expected number of comparisons as a function of $M$ and $t$

Tags: sorting

I stumbled upon [this problem](http://algo.inria.fr/AofA/Problems/src/Q2.stat.txt) on a [list](http://algo.inria.fr/AofA/Problems/) of open problems in the analysis of algorithms dating back to 1997. Is it still open? Can anyone point to a reference with a full or partial solution, or at least discussion?

Problem description (see link for more context):

> Let $C_n$ be the number of comparisons made by quicksort to sort
>   a random permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, when using the median of a
>   sample of size $2t+1$ to perform the partitions and the recursive
>   calls stop at subfiles of size $M\ge 2t+1$.  Both $M$ are $t$ are constants.
>   Compute the expected value of $C_n$ [as a function of] $M$ and $t$.

Comment: How many comparisons does it take to compute the median?  I'm pretty sure that's also open, and would be necessary to get the linear term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a reply from the problem author, wanted to post the info here for reference:

Apparently the problem was solved by Pascal Hennequin in his PhD thesis. Chern and Hwang discuss the solution in [Transitional behaviors of the average cost of quicksort with median-of-(2t+1)](http://algo.stat.sinica.edu.tw/hk/?p=51).

I also found that googling `quicksort "2t+1"` yields the above paper :).